# What is the foundational support for interpreting prophecies as having dual fulfillments?

Tags: prophecy, matthew

There are a handful of prophecies that Christians consider as having ["dual fulfillments"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_fulfillment) - one at the time, and one in the future. Matthew 24, Isaiah 7:14, etc. are examples.

Where did this method of interpretation originate, and more importantly upon what foundation / first-principles does it rest? One could say, let's give it three interpretations, or let's say it was a failed prophecy, or let's say the original prophecy was fulfilled - but in a different way, etc. but instead Christians choose to utilize this Dual Fulfillment method on many prophecies.

The explanation I've come across typically goes something like: "the first prophecy did not fully come about, so we'll see it fully happen sometime in the future." But, that's an obvious [False Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma), as there are many other ways to explain the first prophecy not being "fully fulfilled". Would appreciate someone with more expertise chiming in.

Comment: providing more examples and which denomination interprets dual fulfillment would be clearer (unless you are looking from a purely biblical basis)

Comment: The whole of the history of Israel, together with its varied relationships with nearby nations, is set forth as a type, which will see fulfillment in the New Testament. _And these all, having obtained a good report through faith, received not the promise: God having provided **some better thing for us**, that they without us should not be made perfect._ Hebrews 11:39,40. This 'method of interpretation' originated with He who provided the entirety of history and scripture. It was not invented by manknd.

Comment: Hi Nigel, dual fulfillment is more general than this one case. For example, the prophecy in the new testament about the sign of the last days is also seen as a dual fulfillment. I'm not looking for case-specific explanation (see paragraph 2 of my original question).

Answer (score 0):

Dr. David Jeremiah wrote this article in 1972:

https://www.galaxie.com/article/gj13-2-02

“The Principle of Double Fulfillment in Interpreting Prophecy”

Jeremiah cites this as showing how old the controversy is:

> The controversy over the principle of “double-fulfillment” in the
> interpretation of prophecy is not a new theological development. As
> far back as Theodore of Mopsuestia, there were conflicting opinions as
> to the validity of applying one prophetic passage to more than one
> situation. Theodore (350–428 A.D.), who was labeled “The Exegete” by
> his contemporaries, refused to accept any prophetic interpretation
> that approached duplicity.

Jeremiah names scholars on both sides of the issue.

My take is that the principle is hinted at here:

> It is the glory of God to conceal things,    but the glory of kings is
> to search things out. (Proverbs 25:2, ESV)

Most prophecy is already presumed to have a meaning. If anything is hidden, by the pigeonhole principle, it must be an additional meaning added to what is already there.

Some such mysteries were revealed to Paul, to the men walking to Emmaus, and to the other Apostles. If that were the end of the matter, we could restrict double fulfillment to the things revealed to the Apostles and named in scripture. However, Revelation tells us of a scroll with seven seals. Those seals would not be immediately removed. Once removed by Christ, new information would be made available to the church. While that information could include new prophecy, it is likely to be comprised mostly of new understanding of existing prophecy.

A potent objection to double fulfillment is that it makes the Bible’s meaning unclear and adds subjectivity to its interpretation. One way this could be remedied is if God hid both the new meaning and a new set of hermeneutical principles that could be used to decode the message.